# How can I write the waitXXX function when trying to check the value in XCUItest

Tags: swift, testing, xcode8

Can anyone help on this:

I want to check the value of a `comboBox` element, but I need some time to get the value as the value is retrieved from the server. How should I write the code?

What I want to check is in fact:

```
(comboBox.value as! String).isEmpty == false
```

I tried as following, but it doesn't work:

```
func waitForValue(element: XCUIElement, waitSeconds: Double) {
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isEmpty == false")
    expectation(for: existsPredicate, evaluatedWith: element.value as!     String, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectations(timeout: waitSeconds) { (error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        let message = "Failed to get vlaue from \(element) after \(waitSeconds) seconds."
        XCTFail(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Thanks, I'm just new here, thanks for help on the code formatting.